# Codeigniter .htaccess: Give public access to all files and folders inside the 'public' folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter 2.0.3 | Apache 2.2.17 | PHP 5.3.4.

I'm want to give access to all the files and subfolders inside the 'public' folder. I've read the articles in the Codeigniter wiki and also all first 5 pages on google results and found nothing that works.

This is the files tree:

```
- application
    - public
        - css
            - style.css
        - img
        - js
- system
- .htaccess
```

And this is the .htaccess I'm using to remove 'index.php' from the URL and try to give access to the folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /CodeIgniter_2.0.3

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Enable access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The website is working and 'index.php' is no longer needed in the URL, but the last condition is supposed to give access to the public folder, but its not working for me, so this `http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.0.3/public/css/style.css`
file is not found.

In config.php I have:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.0.3/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Please help.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Which folder is your DocRoot? I'm assuming it's `public`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current structure, you need to change the last `RewriteCond` to:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|application\/public|robots\.txt)
```

because your `.htaccess` is in the same directory as your application folder and your public folder is in your application folder, you need to explicitly mark the application/public folder as accessible.

Comment: I will say, however, that your structure is not the norm. Usually, your `public` folder is adjacent to your application and system folders, not inside either of them.

Comment: Thanks, just moved 'public' up in the tree and its working great!